# No field for implicit collection error in xstream

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xstream

I have been trying to use XStream to convert XML (which is in string format from flash frontend and I have full control on the xml structure).

```
<consistsOf>
 <content>
  <name>Rice</name>
  <price>22</price>
 </content>
 <content>
  <name>chicken</name>
  <price>44</price>
 </content>
</consistsOf>
```

I am trying to get the data into an object by using following code:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
            xstream.alias("consistsOf", ContentsList.class);
            xstream.alias("content", Contents.class);
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(ContentsList.class, "consistsOf");
```

And I get this error:

> No field "consistsOf" for implicit collection

Please help!

Comment: have you looked at http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html?

Comment: But i don't understand how do I use this method when i have multiple contents in the root node? I mean I have already tried somenthing like: Contents content = (Contents)xstream.fromXML(consistsOfXML);

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
public class ContentsList {

...

    public List<Contents> consistsOf;

...

}
```